# Creating Cloud Document Server in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, cloud

Are there any free C# Asp.Net API's to host a server that has cloud capabilities.

All I really want is for users to be able to download Word Documents, The server marks it as locked. Then the user can edit and click "SAVE AS" And it saves it back to my server.

I dont want to use a third party server for this it.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft .Net Framework is a free API that has cloud capabilities (ASP.Net).

You will have to implement the code to present the documents and lock them. And find a way to expose the server to the web.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Sharepoint to me. A foundation version with the functionality you describe comes free with Small Business Server